# Problem in solving a simple Bayesian network.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, bayesian

I want to calculate the probability given in the red in image attached. Can I apply simple Bayesian rule? 
If yes, what can be the first step?

[image: the bang makes it display]

So I tried to solve using Bayesian Rule. But, I don't know if I have taken the first step right. If so, How can evaluate the individual terms..
Thank You.

My Try:
[image: Repeat. The bang makes it display]

Comment: What do you have against typing?  Here's a link to the [Mathjax Basic Tutorial and Quick Reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

No.

Use Bayes' Rule and the Law of Total Probability

It is not *that* hard.

The first step is: $\mathsf P(A\mid B) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(B\mid A)\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(B)}$ where $B=X_1\cap X_2\cap \neg X_3$.

The next step will be: $\mathsf P(B)={\mathsf P(B\mid A)\,\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B\mid \neg A)\,\mathsf P(\neg A)}$ .

Notice also, from the DAG, that $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are mutually conditionally independent when given $A$.

Put it together.
$\phantom{\mathsf P(A\mid X_1,X_2,X_3^\mathsf c) = \tfrac{\mathsf P(X_1\mid A)\,\mathsf P(X_2\mid A)\,\mathsf P(X_3^\mathsf c\mid A)\,\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(X_1\mid A)\,\mathsf P(X_2\mid A)\,\mathsf P(X_3^\mathsf c\mid A)\,\mathsf P(A)~+~\mathsf P(X_1\mid A^\mathsf c)\,\mathsf P(X_2\mid A^\mathsf c)\,\mathsf P(X_3^\mathsf c\mid A^\mathsf c)\,\mathsf P(A^\mathsf c)}}$

Comment: Hi @Graham Kemp...I did the first step and attached in the image in the question. Would you please check if I have taken the first step right. How can I solve the nominator and denominator individually....

Comment: You've got the numerator: $\mathsf P(X_1,X_2,\neg X_3\mid A)\,\mathsf P(A)=\mathsf P(X_1\mid A)\,\mathsf P(X_2\mid A)\,\mathsf P(\neg X_3\mid A)\,\mathsf P(A)$. $~$ The denominator is similar, once you apply the Law of Total Probability. @AbdulKarimKhan

Comment: So according to the total probability rule my denominator will be **P(X1,X2,¬X3)=P(X1∣X2,¬X3)P(X2∣¬X3)P(¬X3)** ..In this I don't know the individual values of these probabilities. I only know these values given A.@Graham

Comment: No,  the Law of Total Probability to use is $\mathsf P(B)=\mathsf P(B\mid A)\,\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B\mid \neg A)\,\mathsf P(\neg A)$ @AbdulKarimKhan

Comment: I calculated and the answer is  0.181. Thank you for the direction. Now I want to calculate **P(X3/X1)=[P(X1/X3).P(X3)]/P(X1)**. The terms **P(X1)** and **P(X3)** can be found using total probability formula. I am confused how to find **P(X1/X3)**?? @Graham

Comment: @AbdulKarimKhan It is the same principle: ${\mathsf P(X_1\mid X_3) ~{= \dfrac{\mathsf P(X_1, X_3)}{\mathsf P(X_3)}\\=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X_1,X_3\mid A)\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(X_1,X_3\mid \neg A)\mathsf P(\neg A)}{\mathsf P(X_3\mid A)\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(X_3\mid \neg A)\mathsf P(\neg A)}\\\ddots}}$

Comment: @Graham..Thank You..I solved it using Total Probability and the answer is 0.5. Thanks for your valuable direction.